# Can I acess a final object's methods?

Tags: java, object, constants, final

I have to declare a parameter on my method final to access it through a **Runnable** but can I  still access the methods? I need to edit the object a bit. I can't seem to find anything that can help me with this question, so hopefully this isn't a stupid question. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

An object is not `final`, but its reference is. So you can easily access its methods (if any) to modify the object.

Comment: I'd actually say it's the *variable* which is final - you can't change the value of the variable to be a different reference. But this is still helpful as-is :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state of the object, even if it is marked `final`. When you mark a reference variable `final`, you can't reassign it to another object, but you can definitely change the state of the object to which it is already referring by calling its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Check this example

```
public class SampleA
{
    private static final SampleB sampleB =  new SampleB();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println( sampleB.toString() );

        sampleB.setM1( "1" );

        System.out.println( sampleB.toString() );

    }

}



public class SampleB
{
    private String m1;

    private String m2;

    public String getM1()
    {
        return m1;
    }

    public void setM1(String m1)
    {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public String getM2()
    {
        return m2;
    }

    public void setM2(String m2)
    {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        final String TAB = "    ";

        String retValue = "SampleB ( "
            + "m1 = " + this.m1 + TAB
            + "m2 = " + this.m2 + TAB
            + " )";

        return retValue;
    }   
}
```